# Why are those instructions generated?

Tags: disassembly, compilers

After disassembling a program, I see the following asm code generated :

```
.text:004D5911 mov     [ebp+var_4], ecx
.text:004D5914 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_4]
.text:004D5917 test    ecx, ecx
.text:004D5919 jnz     short loc_4D591F
```

I don't get why `[ebp+var_4]` is copied back to `ecx`.

Is this an artifact (missed optimization) from the compiler which requires test to take registers as operands?

Comment: You answered your own question. Yes.

Comment: This might also be part of a loop that starts at 4D5914, with the first instruction initializing the loop control variable. Though this seems unlikely, since a) the jnz jumps if cx is *not* zero, and b) this seems to be an IDA disassembly, and ida would have generated a loc_... label if there was a jump to this address.

Comment: I've also seen compilers do this for alignment reasons. inside a particular section

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pattern in assembly generated by gcc at least. When it is not asked to optimize the generated code, the translation between C and asm is really straightforward. One statement in C produces a few lines of asm. Next statement: a few more lines of asm, and so on.

In your case:

```
mov     [ebp+var_4], ecx
```

is probably the end of a line of C, while:

```
mov     ecx, [ebp+var_4]
```

is the beginning of the next one.

These instructions are optimized out as soon as `-O1` (or higher) is provided.

Comment: Optimization, as mentioned in this answer, will eliminate this oddity which you have correctly identified as a compiler artifact.  Things like these are quite useful for figuring out whether code was "hand written", compiled or, potentially, identifying which compiler was used to build a particular piece of code.