# Cannot understand var passing to function in code compiled with dev c++

Tags: disassembly, c

I'm not understating why the parameters to printf are passed this way.
mov     [esp+20h+var_1C], eax
mov     [esp+20h+Format], offset Format ; "%d"

Why esp is added with 20h then substracted with 20h and esp doest added to point to next stack location for local vars ?

why the compiler simply didnt generate code like this:
move eax, var_4
push eax
move eax, Format
push eax
call printf

Ill be happy i some of you can either explain how push is replaced with this custom mov.

here is the source in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b = 5;

    printf("%d", b);

    return 0;
}
```

here is the disassembly:

```
; Attributes: bp-based frame

; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
public _main
_main proc near

Format= dword ptr -20h
var_1C= dword ptr -1Ch
var_4= dword ptr -4
argc= dword ptr  8
argv= dword ptr  0Ch
envp= dword ptr  10h

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub     esp, 20h
call    ___main
mov     [esp+20h+var_4], 5
mov     eax, [esp+20h+var_4]
mov     [esp+20h+var_1C], eax
mov     [esp+20h+Format], offset Format ; "%d"
call    _printf
mov     eax, 0
leave
retn
_main endp
```

Comment: See [Why are those instructions generated?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/why-are-those-instructions-generated)

Comment: This isnt answered my question.

Comment: If [Why are those instructions generated?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/why-are-those-instructions-generated) doesn't answer your question, you may need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe my [answer to this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9079/computing-subtracted-stack-space-for-a-function-manually/9087#9087) will help you, it has some graphics on what the stack looks like when using standard push/pop operations, and how that changes with gcc's optimizations that leave the stack pointer alone.

Answer (score 1):

`push eax` is precisely identical to

```
sub esp, 4
mov [esp], eax
```

Rather than using a bunch of `push`es, they adjusted the stack pointer to where it *would* have been if they *had* used `push`.  Then, they store each datum where it would have been.  The effect is the same, it's just fewer instructions.

Comment: You mean that this peace of code:                                                        mov     [esp+20h+var_4], 5
mov     eax, [esp+20h+var_4]
mov     [esp+20h+var_1C], eax
mov     [esp+20h+Format], offset Format ; "%d"                                        replaces the pushes before function call ?

Comment: @igal yes, but you skipped the `sub` instruction that reserves stack for those `mov`s to go into.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard GCC-generated prelude of a function.

```
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
```

aligns stack on 16-byte boundary, then

```
sub     esp, 20h
```

reserves all stack used inside the function (also aligned on 16-byte boundary, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). Then all operations with current local stack variables, including arguments to called functions, are done as

```
mov     [esp+20h+XXX]
```

MSVC 2010 (and probably others) would do more pushes instead of this mov-ing

Comment: I understand, but why the pushes replaced with moves in newer version of the compilers ?

Comment: @Igal A wild guess - the changed it for x64 and reused the code for x86. Check "Stack Pointer based local variable access" in http://www.codemachine.com/article_x64deepdive.html

Answer (score 0):

> Why esp is added with 20h then substracted with 20h and esp doest
>   added to point to next stack location for local vars ?

The `mov [esp+20h+Format], offset Format` instruction is only a modified view of the `mov [esp], offset Format`. The disassembler tries to visualize the local variables and the stack frame in this way. The `+20h` is the size of the stack frame and the `Format` keyword means the offset of the `Format` parameter (`-20h`). Since it is a parameter, which will be passed to a function, it is placed at the top of the stack. It would be the same, if the function allocated only `18h` stack frame and pushed the parameter values to the stack.

> why the compiler simply didnt generate code like this:
>
> ```
> mov eax, var_4
> push eax
> mov eax, Format
> push eax
> call printf
> ```

Because the stack pointer should not be modified in this way and this form is only 1 instruction and not 2.

Answer (score -2):

HIgh and midlevevel languages has bascically two different calling conentions (assuming datawidth i  max_bits, much faster, but maybe lesss readable, signed values are indicated by, LSHB * 1 and son on.

The assmbly codes not corrrect. The correct code is mov ["I"ESP),
determindes the sign. Sihn is entirely determined på software. EVen simple asseblers and compilers havea sign Array/CLT classl

Comment: I fail to understand your answer, and even if i could understand it, i wouldn't know how it has anything to do with the question.